# How can I use P5 Vector methods in react with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, p5.js

I'm new to p5.js and I'm trying to convert what I learned in a tutorial from the [Coding Train](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4hA7G3gup-4) into a NextJS app with React and Typescript.

I have this Vehicle class but when I try to use any Vector methods I get that Vector is not found:

```
import * as p5 from "p5";

export default class Vehicle {
  pos: p5.Vector;
  target: p5.Vector;
  vel: p5.Vector;
  acc: p5.Vector;
  r: number;
  maxspeed: number;
  maxforce: number;

  constructor(p5: p5, x: number, y: number) {
    this.pos = p5.createVector(p5.random(p5.width), p5.random(p5.height));
    this.target = p5.Vector.random2D();
    this.vel = p5.createVector(10,20);
    this.acc = p5.createVector();
    this.r = 15; //radius
    this.maxspeed = 5;
    this.maxforce = 0.1;
  }

   behaviors(p5: p5) {
    let arrive = this.arrive(p5, this.target);
    this.applyForce(arrive);
  }
 
   applyForce(force) {
    this.acc.add(force);
  } 

  seek(p5:p5, target) {
    let desired = p5.Vector.sub(target, this.pos);
    desired.setMag(this.maxspeed);
    let steer = p5.Vector.sub(desired, this.vel);
    steer.limit(this.maxforce);
    return steer;
  } 

  arrive(p5: p5, target: p5.Vector) {
    let desired = p5.Vector.sub(target, this.pos);
    let distance = desired.mag();
    let speed = this.maxspeed;
    if (distance < 100) {
      speed = p5.map(distance, 0, 100, 0, this.maxspeed);
    }
    desired.setMag(speed);
    let steer = p5.Vector.sub(desired, this.vel);
    steer.limit(this.maxforce);
    return steer;
  }


  update() {
    this.vel.add(this.acc);
    this.pos.add(this.vel);
    this.acc.mult(0);
  }

  show(p5: p5) {
    p5.stroke(255);
    p5.strokeWeight(5);
    p5.point(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
  }
}
```

[image]

according to my package.json I'm using : "@types/p5": "^1.4.2", and "react-p5": "^1.3.30", as a wrapper. any idea of how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is confusing and hard to explain properly, but it has to do with using P5 in instance mode.  The `p5` variable in your constructor refers to the `p5` instance variable that you pass in as an argument, **not** to the imported package.  The `Vector` object exists in the package but not on the instance.

Your code needs to access both the package and the instance, so you'll need two separate variable names.

For example:

```
import * as p5Package from "p5";
```

```
constructor(p5Instance: p5Package.p5InstanceExtensions, x: number, y: number) {
    this.pos = p5Instance.createVector(p5Instance.random(p5Instance.width), p5Instance.random(p5Instance.height));
    this.target = p5Package.Vector.random2D();
```

Or more simply:

```
import * as p5 from "p5";
```

```
constructor(p: p5, x: number, y: number) {
    this.pos = p.createVector(p.random(p.width), p.random(p.height));
    this.target = p5.Vector.random2D();
```

(The `p5.p5InstanceExtensions` type is more technically correct, but they'll both work).

You could also avoid the issue of the ambiguous variable by importing `Vector` directly:

```
import { Vector, p5InstanceExtensions } from "p5";

export default class Vehicle {
  pos: Vector;
  /*...*/

  constructor(p5: p5InstanceExtensions, x: number, y: number) {
    this.pos = p5.createVector(p5.random(p5.width), p5.random(p5.height));
    this.target = Vector.random2D();
```

[Here's a similar discussion on the Processing forums.](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/20509/how-to-call-static-p5-vector-methods-in-instance-mode.html)